# Can I create a contact in a particular contact group on Android 2.2?

Tags: contacts

Is there a way to add a new contact into a particular contact group which I have in my Google contacts? Similarly, is there any way to move contacts from one group to another?

It seems as of now, I can only create contacts on Android but cannot put them in any specific group. To do that, I've to use the web interface of Google contacts.

Comment: FWIW, the version of android you are running is important here. This is something that I believe was added later. Go to Settings / About Phone to find that out.

Comment: This may also depend on the specific distribution of Android; different distributions might include different contact applications. The contact application on my stock android 2.2 doesn't have this option.

Comment: You can always install third party contact apps..

Answer (score 2):

Open the contact, click menu-->edit and scroll down.
You should see a drop down box titled groups just below the email addresses.  Click that and you can then select the groups the contact should be a member of.

Comment: I dont see this option. What version of the software is running on your phone?

Comment: Android 2.2 on the HTC EVO.  It might be an HTC specific feature.  Which phone do you have?

I'll try to upload some screenshots later today

Comment: Confirming not on Moto Droid 2.2.   Btw, you can open the contact menu by long-pressing it in the contact list.

Answer (score 1):

I have Android 2.3.3 on Samsung Galaxy Ace and it doesn't have any option to edit the groups. I'm managing the contact groups from GMail and then sync. It's a standart feature on Android 3. You can use a third party application to manage your contacts. Some applications have the ability to edit contacts' groups. *(DW Contacts & Phone & Dialer)*